# Extern keyword and unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, symbols, extern

I drew a little graph in paint that explains my problem:

But it doesn't seem to show up when I use the `<img>` tag after posting?

Graph:

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/103gcbk.jpg]

Comment: As you can see, code is simpler than pictures.  Pare your code down to the absolute fewest lines that show your problem.  Post those.  Pictures aren't as accurate as a slimmed-down-to-the-essential-problem code snippets.

Comment: That picture tells *nothing*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate the database outside of main(), otherwise you will just declare a local variable shadowing the global one.

GameServer.cpp:

```
#include GameSocket.h
Database db(1, 2, 3);
int main() {
   //whatever
}
```

Comment: Minor point, but it doesn't shadow a global, because there is no global - just a reference to one that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the scope of the declaration of db.  The code:

```
extern Database db;
```

really means "db is declared *globally somewhere*, just not here".  The code then does not go ahead and actually declare it globally, but locally inside main(), which is not visible outside of main().  The code should look like this, in order to solve your linkage problem:

### file1.c

```
Database db;
int main ()
{
  ...
}
```

### file2.c

```
extern Database db;
void some_function ()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: And that does it.  "[some var] is declared globally somewhere, just not here". Every other answer regarding the extern keyword lacked this explanation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The extern is being applied to all the CPP (and resulting OBJ) files, so none of them ever actually instantiate the DB.

Here's one way around this.  In Database.h, change the `extern Database db` to:

```
#ifdef INSTANTIATE_DB
Database db;
#else
extern Database db;
#endif
```

and then in one of your CPP files (Database.cpp would be good, if you have one) add a `#define INSTANTIATE_DB` before the `#include "Database.h"`.

Comment: You can do it that way, but it isn't particularly clean.